# Kivymd 1.2.0 update is not reflecting

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I just updated kivymd to the latest version but the new features are not showing

I tried importing MDListItem from kivymd.uix.list but I keep getting ImportError: cannot import 'MDListItem' from kivymd.uix.list

Please can anyone help me out

Comment: Hi @TSC, welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a minimal code example that exhibits your problem. In this case, you may want to also want to add running that code example so we can exactly how you called it and what the results are.